# Show that $ f(p) \approx \sum_{k=0}^n f (\tfrac{k}{n}) \binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}$

Tags: fitting, random-walk

I have a probability question.  We have a function $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ that we would like to estimate.  So we use the Bernstein polynomials and write:

$$  f(p) \approx \sum_{k=0}^n f (\tfrac{k}{n}) \binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{N-k}$$

Mathematicians would say this convergence is **uniform** on [0,1].  Nonetheless I noticed this is the expected value of a biased random walk after $N$ steps.  Our random variable $X_n = x_1 + \dots x_n$ taking values on the set $\{ 0, 1, 2, \dots, n\}$  with $x_i \in \{ 0,1\}$ at random with probability $p$ or $1-p$.

$$ f(x) \approx \mathbb{E}[\,f(\tfrac{X_n}{n})\,]$$

**What does it mean to let $p$ vary from $0$ to $1$ ?** --- I have never seen a model that lets the probability vary like this.  This might run under a different name in the statistics literature:

- [mixture distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution)
- [student t-distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution)
- [maximum likelihood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood_principle)

I really don't know.

---

This is called the Weierstrass approximation theorem.  Here is the paper by [Levasseur](http://ocw.nctu.edu.tw/course/fourier/supplement/Probabilistic%20Proof.pdf) if interested.

Interestingly the Berenstein polynomials are also the basis of the Bezier curves (and de Casteljau algorithm) as well as NURBS and other splines.  These are use in computer graphics to design the shapes of our alphabets and many other things.

Comment: This seems to be taking an expected value of $f(k/n)$ where $k$ is distributed as a [Binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) with parameter $p$ and $n$ trials, for which the expected value of $k/n$ is $p$?

Comment: @GeoMatt22 yes exactly.  this formula could be a lot of things, such as theory of **unbiased estimators**

Comment: I found a similar formula in Ch 3 of these [notes](http://www.stat.math.ethz.ch/~geer/mathstat.pdf)

Comment: Yes  (Re: "could be a lot of things"). Just to be clear, I was also pointing out that it is something like $f(x)\approx \mathbb{E}[f(y)]$, where $\mathbb{E}[y]=x$. I do not think that the second part was explicitly stated in your question.

Comment: Is this a [tag:self-study] question? The meaning of "$\approx$" does not seem precise enough to give a definite answer. (Does it mean the difference converges to $0$ as $n\to\infty$? For some sense of "converge")

Comment: John, it is not clear what your precise question is. Perhaps the following comment will be of some use. Consider a continuous function $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ and a sequence of "approximants" $$f_n(p)=\mathbb E_p f(S_n/n) = \sum_{k=0}^n f(k/n) \binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{N-k},$$ where $S_n \sim \mathrm{Bin}(p,n)$. Then, $(f_n)$ is just a sequence of real-valued polynomials on $[0,1]$. Now, if you can show that $|f_n(p)-f(p)| = |\mathbb E_p f(S_n/n) - f(p)| \to 0$ uniformly in $p$, then you'll be done. But, this is just a consequence of the WLLN followed by an application of Jensen's inequality.

Comment: @cardinal We are taking the expectation $\mathbb{E}(f)$ with respect to **all** binomial distributions... What is the statistical term for letting probability $p$ vary from $0$ to $1$. ?

Comment: No, John. You're taking the expectation for each *fixed* $p$.

Comment: @cardinal no.  $p$ is varying.   is there a meaning when I differentiate with respect to $p$ ?

Comment: John, you are computing expectations for each *fixed* $p$. This (rather obviously) yields a function of $p$, which is what is then analyzed. There is nothing particularly mysterious here; for example, by way of analogy, think about how statistical inference of $p$ would be done in the usual setting. We'd look at the likelihood of our data (as a function of $p$!) and try to determine what our best guess of it is by maximizing over this variable.